# Eclipse: out of memory issue in eclipse mars IDE

Tags: eclipse, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms2000m
-Xmx3512m
```

Please help me to solve my issue, I've changed xms,xmx to 512,1024,2048, even 3072 also but it's showing same problem as **GC** out of memory in eclipse mars,

Comment: Out of memory doing what?

Comment: when am building project in eclipse , it's showing GC out of memory and automatically eclipse is existing ,